# Use ruby syntactic sugar to print different strings depending on the format of the string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string

I have a method `is_numeric?` which checks if a string is numeric.

I would like to print out the string to the console as part of a sentence, if the string is numeric I would like to surround it in `'` marks.

At present I have something like this...

```
def i_hate_james_blunt_this_much(how_much)
    if how_much.is_numeric?
        puts "a hate james blunt this much : '" + string + "'\n"
    else
        puts "a hate james blunt this much : " + string + "\n"
    end
end
```

but I am sure ruby has some syntactic sugar to make it look sweeter, anyone?

Comment: Why do you want quotes if it's a number, but no quotes otherwise?

Comment: actually the example I gave isn't exactly what my code looks like :) I am generating text for a config file in yaml and I want the values to always be in string format, the yaml library generates integers if the values are numeric unless you put quote round them

Comment: "\n" at the end is redundant if you are using `puts`.

Comment: @whatsthebeef: I know where you're coming from! I used to have `454` in a yaml file, and it meant [this 454](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/454_Life_Sciences) [not the number](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=454_%28number%29&redirect=no)! Why not ask if it's possible to do that directly (in a seperate question) unless I beat you to it?

Comment: I understand the simplest way to get the snakeyaml library generating numbers as string is to surround the number with quotes, this is pretty simple for me to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
output_string = "a hate james blunt this much : "
output_string += how_much.is_numeris? ? "'#{string}'" : string
```

Answer (score 1):

Another variant:

```
hate = how_much.is_numeric? ? "'#{how_much}'" : how_much
puts "i hate james blunt this much : #{hate}\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
q = how_much.is_numeric?? "'" : ""
```

And then

```
puts "a hate james blunt this much : %s%s%s" % [q, how_much, q]
```

or

```
puts "a hate james blunt this much : " + q + how_much + q
```